# Testing values of an array

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm

So challengers, I have an array which I construct with a loop 
And I want to check if two indexes with a different codes were in the array

So my array is like :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 3f 
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => 3s
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2f
    )
)
```

Here there's two indexes 2 and they don't have the same code '3s' and '2f' so it's an error

another example

```
$err=array();
array_push($err, array(1,'2f'));
array_push($err, array(2,'3f'));
```

Here if the new entry is `array_push($err, array(2,'4f'));` how can I check if there's the index 2 in the array and the no similarity of the code

Comment: What do you mean by "test their two codes"? If you know that an element is present in an array, why not read it out and perform whatewver comparison you want to perform?

Comment: So if i understand you correctly the `$file->INDEX` has to always be incrementing by 1. So to test that you could compare it to your `$i+1`? And if all the codes have to be the same then I guess you could say that they all have to match the very first code you enter. So save the `$file->CODE` from the first element in a separate variable and compare every new entry to that code before inserting it.

Comment: @NicoHaase I must test the codes, because if the two elements has the same codes there's no error

Comment: @DirkScholten no the codes must be the same for two similar indexes not for all

Comment: unable to understand your problem.

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat I just reformulate the problem.

Comment: I would change your array to `[1=>3f, 2=>3s]` then you can use the key + value.  `isset($array[2]) && $value != $array[2]`  For example `array_column($array, 1,0)` to format it, but this will remove duplicates.

Comment: @Gavroch You already have an array and want to filter values based on your condition or you want to have this check on every insert of a new key-value?

Answer (score 0):

I might've interpreted this the wrong way, but for me it seems that the last example you gave might be incorrect and rather be that on element 3 it should be `0 => 2, 1 => '3s'` (after your edit you confirmed my suspicion)

So my interpretation is that you want to check if a same INDEX but a different CODE exists in your dataset.

To check for that, you can use a 1-dimensional array and perform the check this way:

```
foreach ($files as $file ) {
    if (isset($this->tab[$file->INDEX]) && $this->tab[$file->INDEX] != $file->CODE) {
         // Failure state
    }

    $this->tab[$file->INDEX] = $file->CODE;
}
```